# Get number of unique values from a column with multiple criteria

Tags: excel

I am working on an Excel problem. Here is my questions:

```
name department year
a      cs        5
b      cs        8
c      cs        2
d      cs        3
a      cs        1
b      cs        10
a      ma        7
f      ma        8
h      ma        2
```

The question is to get the number of unique name (only occur once) with department="cs" and year >2, in this case the result is 2 (i.e,"a" and "d" only occur once).

I knew the formula below might do the trick, but did not know how to put the range filtered by department="cs" and year >2 into the below formula.

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(range, range)=1,1,0))
```

Comment: what about `c` it only occurs once.

Comment: as year >2, so c is not included

Comment: I should have seen that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(A:A,A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),B:B,"cs",C:C,">2")=1)*(B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",A:A))="cs")*(C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",A:A))>2))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: ScottCraner: Clearly this does the job but how do you generate the unique list with this? Guess coming from Countifs part.

Comment: Yes the sumproduct causes the second criterion in the COUNTIFS to iterate.  So it is the same if you put the countifs() in D2, only referring to A2 and dragging down.  This will cause all four `a` in Column A to return 1 or true.  so then we need to continue to filter only to count the one we want inside the sumproduct.  @QHarr

Comment: Thanks Scott for the quick reply. As we update this source data regularly, so the number of rows varies in every update. How can I change this formula to enable auto update (dont need to change row index) for counting unique name?  I tried to change it as =SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,"cs",C:C,">2")=1)*(B:B="cs")*(C:C>2)), but it returns 0.

Comment: @splin never mind, no you cannot use full columns, it short-circuits and returns 0.  How many max do you think will be needed?

Comment: Thank you Scott for the explanation. Can you suggest what is the normal way to handle this auto update without manually editing the row index, and also avoid huge unnecessary calculation.

Comment: @splin I edited the formula to be dynamic.  It will grow or shrink based on the data and only do the number of iterations needed.

Comment: @splin remember that if this works for you then please mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,B2:B10,"cs",C2:C10,">2")=1)*(B2:B10="cs‌​")*(C2:C10>2)), is it the original formula you wrote? I tried this one and it now returns 0, anything wrong here?      You dynamic solution works fine!

Comment: there are some weird characters in the string that can't be seen.  It happens sometimes with copy and paste from the comments.  Clear the formula and retype it. @splin

Comment: You are brilliant, yes, I did copy and paste it from the comment, as I crashed the excel when running =SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,"cs",C:C,">2")=1)*(B:B="cs‌​")*(C:C>2)), and the previous formula is thus not saved. Thank you again Scott!